# Relative pronoun "après laquelle"

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

Can the following sentence be said in three different ways, even without using the phrase "après laquelle"? Do they differ in register or in some other aspect?

> C'est après la gloire qu'il court.
>
> C'est la gloire après laquelle il court.
>
> C'est la gloire qu'il court après.

Comment: In French we mostly tend to use the active form. Indeed, we would rather say *il court après la gloire* than *la gloire après laquelle il court*. Although this is perfectly understandable, using the passive form can slow the flow of the conversation, as it requires an effort (quick effort but one nonetheless) for a Native French to replace the person who is after glory. As for your original question, the first two are right, the last one is completely wrong. They do not differ in register of any some other aspect known to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La plus correcte :

> C'est après la gloire qu'il court.

En supprimant le *qu'*

> C'est la gloire après laquelle il court.

La dernière est totalement incorrecte, elle pourrait être entendue dans la bouche d'un très jeune enfant qui commence à assembler ses phrases.

Comment: + pour « enfant »